# How to get unique values for each column in HIVE/PySpark table?

Tags: hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in HIVE/PySpark with A, B and C columns.
I want to get unique values for each of the column like

```
{A: [1, 2, 3], B:[a, b], C:[10, 20]}
```

in any format (dataframe, table, etc.)

How to do this **efficiently** (in parallel for each column) in HIVE or PySpark?

Current approach that I have does this for each column separately and thus is taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `collect_set()` from the `pyspark.sql.functions` module,

```python
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a',10),(2,'a',20),(3,'b',10)],['A','B','C'])
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  a| 10|
|  2|  a| 20|
|  3|  b| 10|
+---+---+---+

>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df.select([F.collect_set(x).alias(x) for x in df.columns]).show()
+---------+------+--------+
|        A|     B|       C|
+---------+------+--------+
|[1, 2, 3]|[b, a]|[20, 10]|
+---------+------+--------+
```